# MVVMCross : How to bind ImageView to local Image (saved in SD Card)

Tags: android, binding, xamarin, mvvmcross

I want to bind my ImageView control to my property URL (it's my image local path like this : /storage/emulated/0/MyFolder/IMG_20160411_094834.JPEG

I try to bind my control like this :

```
 <ImageView
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ImagePreview"
    local:MvxBind="ImageUrl ImagePath" />
```

ImagePath is my property but i can't use this method.

Can you help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `Mvx.MvxImageView`.

Changing `ImageView` to `Mvx.MvxImageView` should fix it.

Ensure, that you have installed the

- File plugin (https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.Plugin.File/)
- DownloadCache plugin (https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.Plugin.DownloadCache/)

in your android and core project.

Comment: Hello, thank for your reply, but i have this error :  
No IMvxImageHelper registered - you must provide an image helper before you can use a MvxImageView

I search in Google and lot of post said : Install DownloadCache plugin

Comment: Install the Downloadcache plugin as well :) https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.Plugin.DownloadCache/

Comment: But now, i have this error :
**Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.Collections.Immutable, Version=1.1.37.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?**  ^^'

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.Immutable/1.1.37 I'm wondering why this isn't in the dependency list of the downloadcache plugin

Comment: Ahh ok. If you install it to your Core project, it should work as well. It's allways a good idea, to install the plugin to your core, too, if you add one.

Comment: Can't install this package : the package does not contain any content file or assembly reference compatible with the infrastructure. For more information , contact the creator Package (translated)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108789/discussion-between-sven-michael-stube-and-naografix).